# Mean-variance mapping optimization (MVMO) in R

Tags: machine-learning, r, optimization, algorithms

Someone know tell me if there is any package in R about Mean-variance mapping optimization (MVMO) algorithm? I already researched, but don't find anything about this.

Comment: So, answering my question, there isn't any implementation in R.